# Die Grammatik des Nebensatzes

Tags: subordinate-clause

> Ich glaube, wenn Sie einen Vorschlag haben, müssen Sie das äußern.
>
> Ich glaube, wenn Sie einen Vorschlag haben, Sie müssen das äußern.

Ich weiß schon, dass das eine einfache Frage ist, aber seit langem frage ich mich welcher Satz der richtige ist.

Comment: Der erste Satz ist richtig.

Comment: Der erste Satz ist korrekt - Du hast hier die übliche Wortfolge in einem wenn-Satz

Comment: Du könntest die Frage noch verbessern wenn Du ergänzt, *warum* Du Zweifel hast. Was spricht für/gegen den einen oder anderen Satzbau?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Ich glaube, wenn Sie einen Vorschlag haben, müssen Sie das äußern.

Der Teil *Ich glaube, …* ist ein einrahmender Hauptsatz als Einleitung. Es bleibt der verkettete Satz

> Wenn Sie einen Vorschlag haben, **müssen** Sie das äußern.

Hier greift wieder die V2-Regel. Vor dem finiten Verb *müssen* steht **genau ein Satzteil**. In diesem Fall der Nebensatz. Daher muss das Subjekt hinter dem finiten Verb stehen.

Alles wird klarer, wenn man die Reihenfolge des Nebensatzes und des zweiten Hauptsatzes ändert:

> Ich glaube, Sie **müssen** das äußern, wenn Sie einen Vorschlag haben.

Wieder steht **genau ein Satzteil**, diesmal das Subjekt, vor dem finiten Verb *müssen*. Interessant ist noch folgender Fall:

> Sie **müssen** das äußern, wenn Sie einen Vorschlag haben, **glaube** ich.
>
> Wenn Sie einen Vorschlag haben, **müssen** Sie das äußern, **glaube** ich.

Der einrahmende Hauptsatz folgt nach, und auch hier muss nach der V2-Regel wieder **genau ein Satzteil** vor dessem finiten Verb *glaube* stehen.